# MongoDB not authorized for query - code 13

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-roles

In MongoDB 2.6.1 I've setup a user with dbAdmin rights:

```
{
        "_id" : "mydbname.myusername",
        "user" : "myusername",
        "db" : "mydbname",
        "credentials" : {
                "MONGODB-CR" : "<some credentials>"
        },
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "mydbname"
                }
        ]
}
```

When I use the mongo shell to connect to the database (using -u and -p on command line) and run a query like this:

```
db.mycollectionname.find()
```

I get this error:

```
error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on mydbname.request", "code" : 13 }
```

Any ideas what can be happening?

So far I've tried adding every role I can find to the user but that hasn't helped.

Comment: can you share the full list of roles you've added so far?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to assign the [`read`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) role to the user in question.

The [`dbAdmin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) role does **not** include read access on **non-system collections**.

Answer (score 21):

For anybody running into this problem against Mongo 3.0.6, I fixed by adding

```
?authMode=scram-sha1
```

at the end of my mongodb uri.

Here are some docs explaining the purpose of [scram-sha1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/)

Comment: after adding this to uri , i was able to run commands using mongobooster and my unique property also worked , can you please explain why ?

Comment: need to add full URI example not helpful answer -1

Comment: I don't agree with your comment and with your taking off a point. The answer says "at the end of the URI", whichever the URI is. Thanks for participating in any case.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @Sebastian's answer, that means explicitely:

> **Grant a Role**
>
> Grant a role using the db.grantRolesToUser() method. For example, the
>   following operation grants the reportsUser user the read role on the
>   accounts database:

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
    "your_user",
    [
      { role: "read", db: "your_db" }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 8):

I’m posting this because I had trouble finding this solution online. The problem is embarrassing but the error message and scenario make it somewhat difficult to figure out so I'm hoping to save someone some pain.
My application was able to establish a database connection, start and serve static pages but every time it tried to execute a query I got this error.

```
MongoError: not authorized on mydb to execute command { count: "urls", query: {} }
```

This error was caused by a userid and password with the wrong separator

```
mongodb://myuserid/mypassword@ds112345.mlab.com:12345/mydb [wrong]
mongodb://myuserid:mypassword@ds112345.mlab.com:12345/mydb [right]
```

While the node application was able to successfully connect to MongoDB, the incorrectly formatted URI caused the driver to skip authentication prior to issuing database commands.

Thanks and a hat tip to the people at mLab support.

Comment: This is actually how Basic HTTP Authentication through URL encoding is defined - any resource that follows this standard (like MongoDB) will demand that same format. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding

Answer (score 4):

In my case helped to add `?authSource=admin` to uri.

So the uri looked like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:password@host:port/database?authSource=admin
```

Comment: Thanks helped me allot. I was used docker and was trying to connect from local node

Comment: thanks for giving proper and   full URI example using the username, password and all

Comment: that's help me too user are dbOwner thx

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error like

err  { MongoError: not authorized on XXXX to execute command { $eval: function(){ return db.tbl_user.find( {

For me role executeFunctions worked. Once you give role your user should look like following...

{
    "_id" : "XXXXX",
    "user" : "USERXXX",
    "db" : "DBXXXX",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "executeFunctions",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "fryendsapp"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a lot of trial and error I solved it by adding the role  "read" to my user but indicating the database as well:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("myUserName",
[{ role: "read", db: "myDataBaseName"}] );
```

Greetings

Answer (score -4):

I was having the same problem until I realized I made a mistake.  I was inheriting a mongo client pointing to a different database from a parent Perl class without realizing it.  Maybe something you can check.