# Application on Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, mongodb, cloud-foundry

I am using Cloud Foundry and I deployed my Spring boot application on Cloud. I have bound the Mongodb Service with my application. When my application is trying to read the data from mongodb I am seeing below error.

Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on cfe5cb4d-2ca8-40f3-9f83-0cc8321e8c19.ACCOUNT_DETAILS' on server IP:Port

At the same time when I am connecting to this db with application deployed on my local systems its working fine.

Please help me if I need to modify anything here in Configuration to make the application on Cloud work ?

Comment: maybe this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619018/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-code-13

Comment: I am also having the same problem. It's because once your application is on cloud foundry. It cannot make the connection to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your VCAP_SERVICES, probably locally you are using the connection parameters directly but on Bluemix you have to use VCAP_SERVICES parsing. 
Please if possible, copy and paste the code section used to connect to MongoDB.

Comment: BlueMix Means ? Sorry I am new to Cloud Foundary. I have just added the Config.xml file which Spring will load and keep the Connection ready for me. I am not doing manually Connection to Mongodb.