# DatabaseException with Scala Play 2.4 ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I created a simple Play-Scala application to test ReactiveMongo and encountered a strange exception. These are the steps:

1. Create a new play-scala app

   `activator new test-mongo`
2. Configure application.conf and build.sbt according to this link (
   http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html)
3. Modify the controller Application.scala

> ```
> package controllers
>
> import play.api._
> import play.api.mvc._
>
> import javax.inject.Inject
>
> import play.api.mvc.Controller
>
> import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
>
> import play.api.Play.current
> import play.api.libs.json._
>
> import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument
> import reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteResult
> import reactivemongo.api.Cursor
>
> import play.modules.reactivemongo._
> import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
> import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection
> import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi
>
> class Application @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)
>   extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
>
>
>   def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("posts")
>   
>   def index = Action.async {
>     val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collection.
>       // find all people with name `name`
>       find(Json.obj("username" -> "Rob")).
>       // sort them by creation date
>       sort(Json.obj("created" -> -1)).
>       // perform the query and get a cursor of JsObject
>       cursor[JsObject]
>
>     // gather all the JsObjects in a list
>     val futurePersonsList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()
>
>     // transform the list into a JsArray
>     val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] =
>       futurePersonsList.map { persons => Json.arr(persons) }
>
>     // everything's ok! Let's reply with the array
>     futurePersonsJsonArray.map { persons =>
>       // Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready." + persons))
>       Ok(persons)
>     }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

4. Run the app and browse the application page. On first run, the following exception will appear. Refresh the page and the data will be displayed.

> ```
> [DetailedDatabaseException: DatabaseException['not authorized for query on posts.posts' (code = 13)]]
> ```

5. The following shows the versions of the software used:

> ```
> Scala: 2.11.6 
> Play: 2.4 
> Mongo: 3.0.7
> ReactiveMongo: 0.11.9
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that the user you are using in your application has enough rights to read the collection posts ? You can refer to similar SO thread about error code 13 raised by mongodb : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619018/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-code-13

Comment: And if you're using a fresh install of MongoDB 3.x, make sure to configure the connection with `authMode=SCRAM-SHA1`

Comment: Yes, authMode=SCRAM-SHA1 has been added and rights have been  granted. It is strange that the "not authorized" exception happens once right after start up the app and browse the app for the first time. It becomes normal on subsequent visits.

Comment: You can try to use `.database` instead of `.db` from the API, to have the DB resolution using network failover (in case of latency).

Comment: @cchantep, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when using play2-reactivemongo 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT. However, the code has to be "cleaned" every time before run.

Comment: The new function is available in stable 0.11.9