# NodeJS, MongoDB, Jade/Pug - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on Apache(localhost works)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache, pug, monk

I'm having some trouble to connect my app in the server(hosted by KingHost)..
On local machine, it works perfectly
On the server, the one thing I do is change the database from localhost to the server, and the port from 3000 to my server...

When I run the app on the server I get:

```
TypeError: /home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/views/index.jade:316
    314|                         h3.section-heading Capitão
    315|                 .row
  > 316|                     each membro, i in capitao
    317|                         .col-sm-4
    318|                             .team-member
    319|                                 img.mx-auto.rounded-circle(src='/img/team/#{membro.imagem}', alt='#{membro.nome}')

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:1755:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:1888:4)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:6670:22)
    at res (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:219:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:380:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:370:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:127:8)
    at tryRender (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

But on localhost it works perfectly...
The databases are equal(see image below)
[image: database server(big), database localhost(prompt)]

The code(what changes between server and localhost)

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/rsracingufrgs') //localhost
//var db = monk('mongodb.rsracingufrgs.com.br/rsracingufrgs01'); //server

var porta = 3000 // localhost
//var porta = 21031 //server
```

The call to the database:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    const db = req.db;
    const async = require("async")

    const names = ['capitao',...]

    const collections = names.map(name => db.get(name) )

    const functions = collections.map(collection => {
        return done => collection.find( {}, done )
    })

    async.series( functions, (err, results) => {
        // "results" is now an array containing [ docs1, docs2, .. ]
        res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: results[0],
            ...
        });
    })
});
```

the Jade code(works on localhost):

```
        .row
            each membro, i in capitao
                .col-sm-4
                    .team-member
                        img.mx-auto.rounded-circle(src='/img/team/#{membro.imagem}', alt='#{membro.nome}')
                        h4 #{membro.nome}
                        p.text-muted #{membro.curso}
                        ul.list-inline.social-buttons
                            li.list-inline-item
                                a(href="mailto:#{membro.email}")
                                    i.fa.fa-envelope
```

Other things that could be important:

- node version: 6.11.1
- npm version: 3.10.10
- mongodb version(installed from npm on server): 2.2.31
  Dependencies from package.json

> ```
> "dependencies": {
>     "async": "^2.5.0",
>     "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
>     "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
>     "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
>     "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
>     "express": "^4.15.4",
>     "express-session": "^1.15.5",
>     "jade": "^1.11.0",
>     "logger": "0.0.1",
>     "mongo": "^0.1.0",
>     "mongodb": "^2.2.31",
>     "mongoose": "^4.11.11",
>     "monk": "^6.0.4",
>     "morgan": "^1.8.2",
>     "passport": "^0.4.0",
>     "passport-auth0": "^0.6.0",
>     "path": "^0.12.7",
>     "request": "^2.81.0"
>   }
> ```

Edit: using the debug code that @Sridhar provided, I got the following result:

```
{ MongoError: not authorized on rsracingufrgs01 to execute command { find: "capitao", filter: {}, projection: {} }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (/home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
    at /home/rsracingufrgs/apps_nodejs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'not authorized on rsracingufrgs01 to execute command { find: "capitao", filter: {}, projection: {} }',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'not authorized on rsracingufrgs01 to execute command { find: "capitao", filter: {}, projection: {} }',
  code: 13 }
```

Comment: Can you log the `err` before res.render? `results` seem to be undefined, that is possible if there are any errors

Comment: That's the thing @Sridhar, the databases are equal on localhost and server..there shouldn't be an error..and can't get an log, I tried to use console.log(err), but won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As per [mongodb error codes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err#L16), 13 corresponds to `Unauthorized`. You can check [MongoDB not authorized for query - code 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619018/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-code-13) for fixing it.

---

**Original answer**

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

It clearly states that `.length` is called on the `undefined` variable. So, I suspect your result[0] will be `undefined`. If you log results, you will know more about the issue.

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');

....

async.series(functions, (err, results) => {
    if (err || _.isUndefined(results)) {
        //general error handling
        console.log(err);
        return res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: []
        });
    }
    res.render('index', {
        env: env,
        capitao: _.isUndefined(results[0]) ? [] : result[0],
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Did it, got some debug code, I editted the question here with the code..can you help @Sridhar? (thanks for this by the way)

Comment: @alvarosps I've updated my answer. Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Perfect, I've sent the link to the db admins(KingHost), so they can work it out...Thanks @Sridhar!

Answer (score 0):

Your value is undefined so only It's through that error. so, please check that value is not undefined before accessing the length property on that variable.